# javascript performance for Array

Tags: javascript, performance

i tried to figure out, what is different between two versions of a small code-snippet in execution. Do not try to understand, what this is for. This is the final code after deleting all the other stuff to find the performance problem.

```
function test(){
    var start=new Date(), times=100000;
    var l=["a","a"];
    for(var j=0;j<times;j++){
        var result=document.getElementsByTagName(l[0]), rl=result.length;
        for(var i=0;i<rl;i++){
            l[0]=result[i];
        }
    }
    var end=new Date();
    return "by=" + (end-start);
}
```

For me this snippets takes 236ms in Firefox, but if you change `l[0]=result[i];` to `l[1]=result[i];` it only takes 51ms. Same happens if I change `document.getElementsByTagName(l[0])` to `document.getElementsByTagName(l[1])`. And if both are change the snippet will be slow again.

After using Google Chrome with DevTools/Profiles I see that a toString function is added when executing the slow code. But i have no chance to get which toString this is and why it is needed in that case.

Can you please tell me what is the difference for the browser so that it will take 5 times longer than the other?

Thanks

Comment: So basically, if you change the functionality to something completely different, or get a totally different element, it takes a different amount of time. Who would have thunk it ?

Comment: No that's the point, it seems like there's nothing different since l[0] and l[1] are both 'a'.

Comment: `Do not try to understand`  That makes it a little difficult for us to help.. :),  but why on earth you want to put the result of a dom list into a getElementsByTagName is way over my head.

Comment: You're setting `l[0]` to `result[i]`, and then in the next iteration, using `l[0]` in `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: You might consider using a service like [MeasureThat](https://www.measurethat.net/) to do benchmarking.

Comment: Lets benchmark it -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/533hc71h/259/

Answer (score 1):

If you only change one of the indexes to 0 or 1, the code doesn't do the same thing anymore. If you change both indexes, the performance remains identical.

When using the same index for reading and writing, what happens is that the value stored in `l[0]` is used in the next call to `getElementsByTagName`, which has to call `toString` on it.

Answer (score 0):

In the code above you use `l[0]` to search for an element. Then you change `l[0]` und search again and so on. If you now change only one of the two uses (not both!) to `l[1]`, you don't change what you are searching for, which boosts the performance.

That is why when you change both it is slow again.